# How do I make Spark consume from the previous offset id on restarting?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am using Spark to consume data from Kafka. On restarting Spark after consuming some data, how do I ensure that Spark will start consuming from the offset that it had left off?

For example, if one on the first run, Spark had consumed till offset id `x`. How do I ensure that on the next run it will start with offset id `x+1`?

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("name");
JavaStreamingContext jssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, new Duration(2000));
Map<String,String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
kafkaParams.put("zookeeper.connect", "127.0.0.1");
kafkaParams.put("group.id", App.GROUP);
JavaPairReceiverInputDStream<String, EventLog> messages =
  KafkaUtils.createStream(jssc, String.class, EventLog.class, StringDecoder.class, EventLogDecoder.class,
    kafkaParams, topicMap, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER_2());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the receiver based approach (which you're using via `KafkaUtils.createStream`), the offsets are saved and handled by the [WAL (Write Ahead Log)](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/01/15/improved-driver-fault-tolerance-and-zero-data-loss-in-spark-streaming.html), which is responsible for resuming your application from the proper offsets. If you want to be able to control exactly where you resume your application from, look into `KafkaUtils.createDStream` and generally the [Direct (receiverless) API streaming approach](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-kafka-0-8-integration.html#approach-2-direct-approach-no-receivers) with the overload taking `fromOffsets: Map[TopicAndPartition, Long]`.

Comment: Will the WAL handle the offset management by itself or do I have to do some configuration?

Comment: You need to enable it via `spark.streaming.receiver.writeAheadLog.enable=true`, and it should take care of things.

Comment: Will this also work if Kafka goes down and restarts?

Comment: @khateeb I've only used the receiver based approach for a short while, haven't done these sort of tests to it. The best way to know is to test it live and see that it works the way you expect it to. I *assume* it should handle Kafka being done properly.